# Login do Google Sign In não funciona nos navegadores Edge e Opera, mais funciona o Google Chrome e Mozilla

Tags: javascript, api, login, google

**Olá pessoal esse é o erro que tenho quando clico no botão de Login do Google nos navegadores Opera e Edge.
O mais estranho que os erros não aparecem no Mozilla e Google Chrome, no Chrome e Mozilla loga de primeira vai normal.**

> Meu có﻿﻿digo javascri﻿pt

```
function onSignIn(response) {
    console.log("1");
    // Conseguindo as informações do seu usuário:
    var perfil = response.getBasicProfile();

    // Conseguindo o ID do Usuário
    var userID = perfil.getId();

    // Conseguindo o Nome do Usuário
    var userName = perfil.getName();

    // Conseguindo o E-mail do Usuário
    var userEmail = perfil.getEmail();

    if(userEmail != ""){
            botaoDeDeslogar(); //aparece o botao de deslogar
            botaoDeLogar();  //esconde o botao de logar      
        }

    if(userEmail == ""){

        }
    // Conseguindo a URL da Foto do Perfil
    var userPicture = perfil.getImageUrl();

    //document.getElementById('user-photo').src = userPicture;
    //document.getElementById('user-name').innerText = userName;
    //document.getElementById('user-email').innerText = userEmail;

    // Recebendo o TOKEN que você usará nas demais requisições à API:
    var LoR = response.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("Token: " + LoR);

};

$('#google_plus_a').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("2");
    e.preventDefault();
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log("3");
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
});



Tambem ja tentei assim 

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// verifica se o usuário está; logado e executa ações
// executa ações se o usuário estiver logado
/*gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    console.log("4");
    gapi.auth2.init({

        client_id: '428001492988-ouocv0d188o1nu3rdhas2dcatahsae1a.apps.googleusercontent.com',

    }).then(function () {
        console.log("5");
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        console.log(auth2.isSignedIn.get()); // Agora isso sempre retorna corretamente 

        if (auth2.isSignedIn.get() == true) {
            botaoDeDeslogar(); //aparece o botao de deslogar
            botaoDeLogar();  //esconde o botao de logar            
            console.log("6");
        } else {
            //usuarioDeslogadoGoogle();
            console.log("7");
        }
    });
});*/

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//Botao de login do google esta aparencedo display block
function botaoDeLogar() { 
    console.log("8");
    console.log("Usuário não esta conectado com o Google deseja logalo BT none!");
    $('#g-signin2').css('display', 'none'); //Botão de login do google desaparece
}

function botaoDeLogar2() { 
    console.log("9");
    console.log("Usuário não esta conectado com o Google deseja logalo BT block!");
    $('#g-signin2').css('display', 'block'); //Botão de login do google aparece
}

// Botao de sair se o usuario estiver logado esta aparencendo display none
function botaoDeDeslogar() {
    console.log("10");
    console.log("O usuário está conectado com o Google deseja desconectalo.");
    $('#google_plus_a').css('display', 'block'); //Botao de sair aparece
}
```

> Meu head onde chama a API do Google

```
<!-- Infomações do google -->
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="428001492988-97ub0g6ijog4n440anrgm706ijg0dqqt.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

﻿

> Erros que a﻿parecem nos navegador﻿es EDGE e OPERA  -  " No Goog﻿le
>   Chrome e Mozill﻿a funcionan normal ".

Erro que aparece no EDGE e no opera quando clico no Botão de  " Login do Google "

---

```
400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, https://www.****************.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/428001492988-97ub0g6ijog4n440anrgm706ijg0dqqt.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=428001492988 to update the authorized JavaScript origins.
Learn more
Request Details
redirect_uri=storagerelay://https/www.************.com?id=auth604459
response_type=permission id_token
scope=email profile openid
openid.realm=
client_id=428001492988-97ub0g6ijog4n440anrgm706ijg0dqqt.apps.googleusercontent.com
ss_domain=https://www.*************.com
fetch_basic_profile=true
gsiwebsdk=2
That’s all we know.`insira o código aqui`
```

---

> Erro que aparece nos console no Opera e no Edge

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:103 Uncaught 

{error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://www..…itelist this origin for your project's client ID."}
details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://www.******.com has not been whitelisted for client ID 428001492988-97ub0g6ijog4n440anrgm706ijg0dqqt.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Parece que a origem passada é inválida, tem que ver como o google sabe qual é a origem, talvez pelo cabeçalho`origin` que pode não ser setado automáticamente pelo navegador

Comment: Guilherme vou dar uma olhada e volto aqui pra lhe falar...

Comment: Guilherme eu add mais não foi ..recebo ainda ----- cb=gapi.loaded_0:103 Uncaught {error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://www.que…itelist this origin for your project's client ID."}

Comment: Erro só aparece no Opera e no Edge nos outros navegadores funciona normal...estou bugado aqui... :D rssrrs